# ObjectListView does not display zero

Tags: python, wxpython, integer, objectlistview

I'm using ObjectListView 1.2 (Python) and is quite confused by the weird behaviour.
I have an object that has a double field. OLV will display the value if it is non-zero (whether it is int or double), but whenever the value is zero it just doesn't display anything for that object in that column.

SSCCE:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/env python

import wx

from ObjectListView import ObjectListView, ColumnDefn

class MyObj:
    def __init__(self, name, id):
        self.name = name
        self.id = id

    @staticmethod
    def getObjects():
        objList = []
        for i in range(0,5):
            objList.append(MyObj("item" + str(i), i))
        return objList

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.Init()

    def Init(self):
        self.InitModel()
        self.InitWidgets()
        self.InitObjectListView()

    def InitModel(self):
        self.songs = MyObj.getObjects()

    def InitWidgets(self):
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer_1.Add(panel, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer_1)

        self.myOlv = ObjectListView(panel, -1, style=wx.LC_REPORT|wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        sizer_2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer_2.Add(self.myOlv, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 4)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer_2)

        self.Layout()

    def InitObjectListView(self):
        self.myOlv.SetColumns([
            ColumnDefn("Title", "left", 120, "name"),
            ColumnDefn("ID", "left", 120, "id")
        ])
        self.myOlv.SetObjects(self.songs)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp(1)
    wx.InitAllImageHandlers()
    frame_1 = MyFrame(None, -1, "ObjectListView Simple Example1")
    app.SetTopWindow(frame_1)
    frame_1.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in `ObjectListView`. Whenever you set up a column with no `stringConverter`, it will ignore all "falsey" values (including zero). A comment in the code indicates that it is supposed to be ignoring `None`, but it catches all other false values as well.

I would normally suggest reporting this bug upstream, but given that the project doesn't seem to have been updated in almost four years, I'm not sure that would be very productive.

Instead, you can fix this by editing your copy of `ObjectListView.py`. The relevant method is in the `ColumnDefn` class:

```
def _StringToValue(self, value, converter):
    """
    Convert the given value to a string, using the given converter
    """
    try:
        return converter(value)
    except TypeError:
        pass

    if converter and isinstance(value, (datetime.datetime, datetime.date, datetime.time)):
        return value.strftime(self.stringConverter)

    # By default, None is changed to an empty string.
    if not converter and not value:                # THE ERROR IS HERE!!!!
        return ""

    fmt = converter or "%s"
    try:
        return fmt % value
    except UnicodeError:
        return unicode(fmt) % value
```

The fix is to change the line indicated to:

```
if not converter and value is None:
```

Comment: Worked flawlessly! Who would've guessed :) Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I would use @Fuzzy answer as it is not a bug of OLV but a feature documented in http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/python/majorClasses.html

Comment: @Werner: It's been a long time since I looked at this, but I still think it's a bug. The documentation you linked to (as far as I can see) and the comment in the code both suggest that it is only `None` that should be replaced by an empty string by default, not all falsey values. Now, the other answer does provide a perfectly good workaround, but that doesn't mean that OLV is working as intended.

Comment: @Blckknght: O.K. this is maybe also personal preference, I most of the time like that None, False, 0 show as blank, it makes the list less 'crowded', so the current OLV behaviour is fine with me. The 'stringconverter' provides an easy way to override the standard behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

As Blckknght's answer mentions, this happens when you don't set a stringConverter.

Rather than edit the lib, I just use `stringConverter="%.0f"` on the end of any column where I'll be listing ints.

Example:

```
self.myOlv.SetColumns([
  ColumnDefn("Title", "left", 120, "name"),
  ColumnDefn("ID", "left", 120, "id", stringConverter="%.0f")
])
```

Comment: I like this. A sound approach. If the OLV gets updated, but the bug not fixed, you will be left with the problem.